# Creating a viewport icon for my blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

A lot of native actors of Unreal has an icon (gismo) that is shown on the viewport. Example: A "Point Light" has a light bulb, a "Player Start" has a joystick and a flag, a "Sphere Reflection Capture" has a metalic ball icon and so on.

Print screen of the mentioned icons:
[image]

How to replicate this behavior to my `Blueprint Class` (let's assume my parent class is `Actor` if it make easier)?
Is there a way to create my icon (as .ico or .png) and use it to represent my blueprint in viewport?

Comment: You can add a "billboard" component to your actor. By default it will by "hidden in game" to be visible only in the editor.

Comment: This is it, can you make an answer, I'll check it as correct.

Comment: Just to be sure you've not missed it, I made the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "billboard" component to your actor. By default it will be "hidden in game" to be visible only in the editor.